# decompressing IMAP deflated message

Tags: compression, imap, deflate, inflate

I have an issue trying to decompress an imap message compressed using deflate method. The things I've tryed so far were isolating one of the directions of an IMAP conversation (using wireshark's follow tcp function) and saving the message data in an raw format that I hope it contains only the deflated message part. I then found some programs like tinf (1st and 3rd example) and miniz (tgunzip example) and tryed to inflate back that file, but with no succes.
I am missing something? Thank you in advance.

tinf - http://www.ibsensoftware.com/download.html
Miniz - https://code.google.com/archive/p/miniz/source/default/source

Comment: IMAP compresses the complete stream, not just the message, so you can't cut a message out of its context. The message depends on the earlier bytes. You have to deflate starting where the server says OK to the COMPRESS DEFLATE command, after the CRLF. Tinf looks like it should decompress that, *if* you get the cut and paste right.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Still get the inflate() failed with status -3

Comment: Mind your cut and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Try piping that raw data to:

```
perl -MCompress::Zlib -pe 'BEGIN{$i = inflateInit(-WindowBits => -15)}
                           $_=$i->inflate($_)'
```

The important part is the `-WindowBits => -15`  that changes the expected format into a *raw* one without adler checksum.

(that's derived from the dovecot source, works for me on Thunderbird to gmail network capture).

From [RFC4978](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4978#section-4) that specifies IMAP compression (emphasis mine):

> When using the zlib library (see [RFC1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951)), the functions
> deflateInit2(), deflate(), inflateInit2(), and inflate() suffice to
> implement this extension.  **The windowBits value must be in the range
> -8 to -15, or else deflateInit2() uses the wrong format**.
> deflateParams() can be used to improve compression rate and resource
> use.  The Z_FULL_FLUSH argument to deflate() can be used to clear the
> dictionary (the receiving peer does not need to do anything).